# Difference between configuring database on zappa app & regular django app

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is there any difference configuring a zappa app & a regular django app? I am following [this tutorial on setting up a zappa app](https://cloudacademy.com/blog/zappa-or-how-to-go-serverless-with-django/#crayon-5b25827866812126721523) and under "Configure the database" it links to paid tutorials - and I can't find much info via searching google.

So is it any different than just changing my `DATABASES` in my settings, installing `psycopg2` and migrating the changes? Or does zappa require something different/more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

You can't run a regular Django app in AWS Lambda, but you can use Zappa to package your Django app as a Lambda-compatible app. There's no need to pay for tutorials to make Django work with Zappa, their [README](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/blob/master/README.md) is fairly detailed. If you Google 'AWS Lambda Zappa Django' you'll find tons of free content as well.

## Long answer

Lambda is not a regular server, there's no direct HTTP access to it, you can only comunicate with a Lambda function through AWS APIs.

What Zappa does is use [AWS API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) (which does expose HTTP endpoints to any client with internet connection) and map API Gateway endpoints with functions/classes in your application (in your case, a Django app). It's kind of a 'hack', because you can't really run a WSGI-app on Lambda.

Zappa kind of 'simulates' running your Djando app, get the response from your app, return it from the Lambda to API Gateway, which then send to the client requesting your endpoint.

Another option similar to Zappa that you should check out is [Serverless](https://serverless.com/). AWS also has an open source and lightweight framework for running Python apps in Lambda which is 
[Chalice](http://chalice.readthedocs.io). If you already have your app developed in Django, you'd need to rewrite it to work in Chalice.